# How to write this $(\exists (x,y) \in R, y- 3x-2 \wedge y = 1-x^2) $in words?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, predicate-logic

I am translating the negation of the statement   $(\exists (x,y) \in R, y= 3x-2 \wedge y = 1-x^2) $

$(\forall (x,y) \in R, y\ne 3x-2 \vee y \ne 1-x^2) $

So far I have, "For every $(x,y)$ there exists a real number such that $y\ne 3x-2 $ or $ y \ne 1-x^2$ "

The reason I am second guessing myself (even if i am correct) is that it doesn't really make sense to me in the form of a sentence. Am I right? If not, any suggestions?

Comment: "For all real numbers $x$ and $y$, $y\not =$..."

Comment: Ok, thank you. so except for the "for all real numbers $x$ and $y$" mine was correct? It just seems like not a natural sentence

Comment: Is $y-3x-2$ a typo for $y=3x-2$?

Comment: Yes, thank you, corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

$$ \lnot (\forall x \in A, \phi(x) \wedge \psi(x))$$

is the same as

$$ \exists x \in A, (\lnot\phi(x)) \vee (\lnot \psi(x))$$

If $\wedge$ and $\vee$ swapped places in the above, you still get a true statement.

If $\exists$ and $\forall$ are swapped places in the above, you still get a true statement.

Your correct if you take out the "the exists part". That is, the correct statement is: "For every $(x,y), y \ne 3x - 2 \vee y \ne 1 - x^2$".

Note that in your case, $A = \mathbb{R}^2$, so elements in $A$ are of the form $(x,y)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

You asked about readability. For the first sentence, you have "There exists a pair $(x,y)$ such Eq1 is true and Eq2 is true". The negation of this statement is that "There doesn't exist a pair $(x,y)$ such that Eq1 is true and Eq2 is true". That is, "For every pair $(x,y)$, either Eq1 is false or Eq2 is false".

Comment: Ok so my negation statement is correct then from you're saying

Comment: Well you said "For every (x,y) there exists real numbers ...". What real numbers are you referring to? It is sufficient to say "For every (x,y), Eq1 is not true or Eq2 is not true".

Comment: When you say "For every (x,y)...", what is implied is "For every pair of real numbers (x,y)...".